# libcurl resume support

Tags: libcurl

Using libcurl, does anybody knows how to determine if a web server supports resuming?

I'm trying to make a custom update software which needs to determine if the web server supports resuming.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean HTTP and then there's really no good way to know until you try it.

Answer (score 0):

you can send a HEAD request firstly with RANGE header, then determine with the response header.